# React Hook "useCustomFunction" cannot be called inside a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been looking for a while and am not understanding how to get around this error.

I have a function that has a useEffect statement inside it.  I need to call this function from within a loop(or map).

### file1

```
export function useCustomFunction(year: number, month: number): any {

  const customers = useAllCustomers();
  const aggregator = useCustomerAggregator(year, month);
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("" as string);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('i am doing stuff here')
    setResponse('hello world')
  }, [year, month, customers, aggregator]);

  return response;
}
```

### file2

```
import { useCustomFunction } from "file1";

export function EMDeltaDashboardPage(){

  const dateCols = ["2022-10","2022-11","2022-12","2023-01","2023-02","2023-03","2023-04"]

  useMemo(() => {
    dateCols.forEach((element: any) => {
      let year = Number(element.split("-")[0])
      let month = Number(element.split("-")[1])
      let budgets = useCustomFunction(year, month);
      console.log(budgets)
  },[dateCols])
```

In this case I am using file2 to call file1 useCustomFunction in a loop and budgets should be 'hello world' and should console.log 7 times.

However I am getting the following error message and am not sure how to get around this.

```
React Hook "useCustomFunction" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant. You can only call hooks in root component function.
Instead of calling your hook each iteration you call it once and return a function which you then call:

```
const myCustomFn = myCustomHook();

dataCols.forEach((col) => {
  // ...
  myCustomFn(year, month));
});
```

Comment: how do you pass variables into myCustomFn?... as in this case myCustomHook takes in variables